# Firefoxos is there a simple way to make my app automatically and only landscape

Tags: screen-orientation, firefox-os

I read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Manifest however it seems pretty unclear to me.

> **orientation**
>
> (Android & Firefox OS only, optional) An array that defines the
> orientations at which the application will stay locked, even if the
> device orientation changes. Each entry in the array can be one of
> portrait, landscape, portrait-primary, landscape-primary,
> portrait-secondary or landscape-secondary. The options containing
> -primary and -secondary lock the orientation in only one device orientation, even if the device orientation changes. The options
> without -primary and -secondary combine both rules of primary and
> secondary together. The options additionally suffixed with -secondary
> imply a 180 degree rotation from the options without the suffix. For
> instance, holding the phone upside down (but still in a manner where
> width is less than height), implies the portrait-secondary
> orientation. If this field has a valid value, the runtime will not
> change the orientation of the view rendering the application even if
> the device is turned. Example:
>
> `"orientation": ["portrait","landscape-secondary"]`

What? So how do I make my app default in landscape mode, and lock in landscape mode no matter what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this manifest value
"orientation": "landscape-primary"

In script you can also try:
screen.mozLockOrientation("landscape-primary");

If you only use landscape, your app will display in landscape but can also rotate 180 degrees.  Using landscape-primary will prevent this from happening.

Comment: Works like a charm! Didn't know `orientation` could also be a single string. Thank you!